# Get username in OnLoggedIn and update user in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql, forms-authentication

I have a script in my `site.master` page that updates an SQL, it works fine as shown below, but instead of updating the `Test` I want to update the user who just logged in.

How do I select the current user?

I've found the following, but do not know if it's right, and where it should be added:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

I use Forms Authentication.

```
<script runat="server">
void OnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //connect to the db
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.
        ConnectionStrings["herning_brand_dk_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
  //the command to increment the value in the LoginCounter column by 1
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_Users SET 
        LoginCounter = LoginCounter+1 WHERE UserName = 'Test'", conn);
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  //update where UserName is Test
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", "Test");
  using (conn)
  {
      //open the connection
      conn.Open();
      //send the query to increment the number
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
  Label1.Text = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT**

This works: (more or less)

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["herning_brand_dk_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_Users SET LoginCounter = LoginCounter+1 WHERE UserName = @UserName", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
//update where UserName is x
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", Login1.UserName);
using (conn)
{
    //open the connection
    conn.Open();
    //send the query to increment the number
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It works with a fresh new Login control named "Login1".
But it does not work with the login control I have converted to template, even when I call it "Login1".

```
<asp:LoginView ID="LoginView1" runat="server">
  <LoggedInTemplate>
    <b>Velkommen: &nbsp;</b>
    <asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" /> &nbsp;  <br /> 
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" LogoutText="Log ud" Font-Size="Small" LogoutPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" /> &nbsp;                  
  </LoggedInTemplate>
  <AnonymousTemplate>
    <asp:Login ID="Login1" OnLoggedIn="OnLoggedIn" runat="server">
      <LayoutTemplate>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
          <tr>
          .....
          .....
```

Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 0):

From the code snippet i would say that you use Login control for the forms authentication. As explained in this example on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx#Y456) you can get the username directly from the Login control itself.

Then, your code would look like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE aspnet_Users SET 
            LoginCounter = LoginCounter+1 WHERE UserName = @UserName", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
//update where UserName is Test
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserName", Login1.UserName);
```

where Login1 is the ID of your Login control. I'm not sure if you can use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

at this point because the authentication just occured on the PostBack and the Context is already initialized. I think you can use the User.Identity after the authentication Request is finished.

Comment: I've tried your example but get the error "the name 'Login1' Does not exist in the current context".
I checked and the login control has the ID=Login1.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. i see you have Label1 control that you access it from the same block. If your Login control has the aforementioned ID and if it's set to runat="server" then you should have access on it in your code behind.

Comment: The Label1 control actually also does not works, I tried to use it for testing purposes but can't get it to work.

Comment: Well, the way you are using Login control as a child control of LoginView brings more details to the table. You can solve this in two ways: 1. Extract the Login control from the Loginview and hide it when user is authenticated, or 2. The quick and dirty hack is to access the Login control through control hierarchy tree like this: Login loginControl = (Login)LoginView1.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("Login1");

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Login control, what you want is this:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
string username = user.UserName;
```